# MIDI and Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I think I have thoroughly searched all the internet for information how to use MIDI on Windows Phone, but I have found nothing yet. Nonetheless there are applications in marketplace that can play midi files, so my question is: Is there a library that allows to play midi files?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To play sound from midi, You need a Synthesizer

a c# impl
http://csharpsynthproject.codeplex.com/releases/view/81244

I tried to use it in a poc to play some simple tunes and it works fine, but with some more complex songs, the performance is a issue.

I think native implementation would be a better choice.